# Twig after update to v2.6.1 - Undefined index: vars - form.vars

Tags: php, twig

I get an error after updating twig

```
- Updating twig/twig (v2.6.0 => v2.6.1):
```

In composer, I have:

```
"symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.1",
```

Error is:

> twig/twig  "Notice: Undefined index: vars"

In template:

```
{{ form.vars.id }}
```

If I put `{{ dump(form) }}`, I see +vars ...

Comment: Did you check this post? https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5064#issuecomment-7285061

Comment: Try turning off the php_twig extention.

Comment: Note: This is Not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133/6216 - it was a bug in the twig library. The linked question is not the problem, nor any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a (known) bug in twig v2.6.1 - https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2810

You can simply not update to that version for now, or explicitly mark it not to install until the next version has been released (it should be in the next day or two at most).

```
# Adding this line to composer.json will ensure that the version will not be installed.
"conflict": {
    "twig/twig": "2.6.1"
},
```

twig/twig v2.6.2 was released later the same day correcting the bug.