# Twig not defined property seems to not work

Tags: symfony, twig

This is my part of code

```
{% if form.offer.increment_order_quantity.vars is defined %}
   1
{% else %}
   2
{% endif %}
```

It shows me "1" even if `form.offer.increment_order_quantity.vars` is not defined. And if instead of "1", I want to dump `{{ form.offer.increment_order_quantity.vars }}`, it tells me that vars is not defined.

Since i launched an update of composer in my Symfony environment ....

Comment: Have you recently updated to Twig v2.6.1?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54181877/6216

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig after update to v2.6.1 - Undefined index: vars - form.vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178827/twig-after-update-to-v2-6-1-undefined-index-vars-form-vars)